# Inject $state or $stateParams into directive not possible with angular ui router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

When I inject $state/$stateParams into the directive they are not available inside the unique function, why?

```
'use strict';
angular.module('TGB').directive('uniqueSchoolclassnumberValidator', function (schoolclassCodeService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$asyncValidators.unique = function (schoolclassNumer) {

                var schoolyearId = 1; // Read schoolyearId from the $stateParams.id but how to inject?
                return schoolclassCodeService.exists(schoolyearId, schoolclassNumber);
            };
        }
    };
});
```

UPDATE

[image]

As you see in my google chrome console $stateParams or $state are undefined!

Comment: no reason they shouldn't be. Where's the code that doesn't work? What does `not available` mean ? Also provide demo that reproduces problem

Comment: See my update with screenshot.

Comment: still not sure where you try to use them ...inside `schoolclassCodeService.exists()`? If so they need to be either injected there or passes as argument

Comment: The schoolyearId is in the state url: base/schoolyears/1/schoolclasses. I need the "1" I can not either inject $state/$stateParams inside the schoolclassCode service. $state/$stateParams can only be injected inside controller, run method etc...

Comment: Really I would like to have a demo, but either I fear when I set everything up it won`t be reproducable as the error is due to my project or I take me some days... so you have to wait :-)

Comment: Are they defined in other controllers or directives?

Comment: $state-/params works in other controllers or in the resolve property as parameter, but I am not hitting any state here. Of course I could backup the schoolyearId in the schoolclassService when the controller for the page is initially loaded, but thats a workaround...

Comment: Why are you trying to validate the id before it's passed to the controller? You could wait until the controller is built and then check it's "uniqueness".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need a `Controller` defined as part of your directive wherein `$stateParams` can be injected. Something along these lines should work (untested)

```
(function (){
angular
  .module('TGB')
  .directive('uniqueSchoolclassnumberValidator', schoolclassDirective);

  schoolclassDirective.$inject = ['$state', '$stateParams', '$compile','schoolclassCodeService'];

  function  schoolclassDirective($state, $stateParams, $compile,schoolclassCodeService) {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      controller : MyController
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, listOfCtrls) {
         // you will need to get the ngModelCtrl from the list of controllers as you have the require field set above
          var ngModelCtrl = listOfCtrls[0]//[1];
          var myCtrl = listOfCtrls[1]//[0];
          ngModelCtrl.$asyncValidators.unique = function (schoolclassNumer) {

            var schoolyearId = myCtrl.id; 
            return schoolclassCodeService.exists(schoolyearId, schoolclassNumber);
          };
       };
    };


  function MyController($state, $stateParams){
      var scope = this;
     scope.id= $stateParams.schoolyearId;
  }

  return directive;
}}
```

Also please go through the usage of `$stateParams` from the [wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service)

The other way to get the `1`which if it is part of a parent state would be to define the `resolve` [function of the parent state](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#important-stateparams-gotcha) and use that within the controller.